Create Azure MSI and Storage account and assign MSI to storage account
Modules
#-------------------
# Managed Identity
#-------------------
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "user_assigned_identity" {
  name                = var.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

}

#-------------------
# Storage Account
#-------------------  
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage_account" {
  name                     = "storageaccountname"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

#-------------------
# Storage Container
#-------------------
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "storage_container" {
  for_each              = var.containers
  name                  = try(each.value.container_name, null)
  container_access_type = try(each.value.access_type, null)
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.name
}

#-----------------
# Role Assignment
#-----------------
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role_assignment" {
  for_each             = var.role_assignments
  description          = try(each.value.description, null)
  role_definition_name = try(each.value.role, null)
  principal_id         = try(each.value.principal_id, null)
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.id
}

Invoke Module
#-------------------
# Storage Accounts
#-------------------
module "storage_account" {
  source = "../modules/storageAccount"

  for_each                        = var.storage_account
  name                            = lower(replace(each.value.name, "/[[:^alnum:]]/", ""))
  resource_group_name             = each.value.resource_group
  location                        = var.location
  containers                      = try(each.value.storage_container, {})
}

#-----------------
# User Identities
#-----------------
module "UserManagedIdentity" {
  source = "../modules/userIdentity"

  for_each            = var.UserManagedIdentity
  name                = lower(each.value.name)
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group
}

TFVARS
storage_account = {
  new_tf_sa = {
    name           = “test”_sa
    resource_group = “learn_rg”
    storage_container = {
      testcontainer = {
        container_name = "tf-states"
        access_type    = "private"
      }
    }
    role_assignments = {
      test_mi_role_assignment = {
        mi_name       = “test_user_identity"
        role          = "Contributor"
        description   = "Assign Contributor role"
      },
        test2_mi_role_assignment = {
        mi_name       = “test2_user_identity"
        role          = "Contributor"
        description   = "Assign Contributor role"
      }
    }
  }
}

UserManagedIdentity = {
#-------------------------------#
# Test Managed Identity #
#-------------------------------#
  test1_user_identity = {
    name           = "mi-test1"
    resource_group = "learn_rg"
  },
    
  test2_user_identity = {
    name           = "mi-test2"
    resource_group = "learn_rg"
  }
  
  }

In above code i am trying to create and storage account and two managed identities in Azure. I want to be able to create multiple storage accounts and managed identities at the same time and assign these managed identities with different roles to these storage accounts. Multiple managed identities can be assigned to a single storage account with different roles.
In tfvars it can be seen I am creating two MSI test1_user_identity and test1_user_identity and I am trying to assign it to new_tf_sa storage account. So for I have the design in mind, I have createtd a role_assignments block for storage accounts but I am not sure how to refer managed identity here since managed identities are also not created so I can not use principal_id, I guess I am struggling to define implicit dependency. I tried to use locals to do that but got error saying The “for_each” set includes values derived from resource attributes that…


Create Azure MSI and Storage account and assign MSI to storage account simultaneously using terraform.

In general, Terraform needs every value should be declared in the module itself by declaring them as variables. Which is missed in your case.
I make few changes in the code as per the requirement for Harshicop while provisioning the particular resource and able to provision the requirment you're looking for.
configuration:
main.tf:(root)
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "learnvks_rg"
  location = var.location
}


module "UserManagedIdentity" {
  source              = "./modules/userIdentity"
  for_each            = var.UserManagedIdentity
  name                = each.value.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

module "storage_account" {
  source              = "./modules/storageAccount"
  for_each            = var.storage_account
  name                = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = var.location
  containers          = each.value.storage_container

  
  role_assignments    = {
    test_mi_role_assignment = {
      principal_id = module.UserManagedIdentity["test1_user_identity"].principal_id  # This is now exported from the userIdentity module
      role         = "Contributor"
    },
    test2_mi_role_assignment = {
      principal_id = module.UserManagedIdentity["test2_user_identity"].principal_id  # This is now exported from the userIdentity module
      role         = "Contributor"
    }
  }
}



modules/usermanagedidentity/main.tf:
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "user_assigned_identity" {
  name                = var.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

output "principal_id" {
  description = "The principal ID of the User Assigned Managed Identity"
  value       = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned_identity.principal_id
}

output "id" {
  description = "The ID of the User Assigned Managed Identity"
  value       = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned_identity.id
}

modules/storageaccount/main.tf:
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage_account" {
  name                     = lower(replace(var.name, "/[[:^alnum:]]/", ""))
  resource_group_name      = var.resource_group_name
  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"
}


resource "azurerm_storage_container" "storage_container" {
  for_each              = var.containers
  name                  = try(each.value.container_name, null)
  container_access_type = try(each.value.access_type, null)
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.name
}


resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role_assignment" {
  for_each = var.role_assignments

  
  principal_id         = try(each.value.principal_id, null)
  role_definition_name = try(each.value.role, null)
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.id


  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_account.storage_account
  ]
}

terraform.tfvars:
storage_account = {
  new_tf_sa = {
    name           = "test_vksbasa"
    storage_container = {
      testcontainer = {
        container_name = "tf-states"
        access_type    = "private"
      }
    }
  }
}

UserManagedIdentity = {
  test1_user_identity = {
    name           = "mi-test1"
    resource_group = "learn_vkrg"
  },
  test2_user_identity = {
    name           = "mi-test2"
    resource_group = "learn_vkrg"
  }
}

role_assignments = {
  test_mi_role_assignment = {
    principal_id = ""  # this will be fetched from the output mentioned in the usermanagedidentity module
    role         = "Contributor"
  },
  test2_mi_role_assignment = {
    principal_id = ""  # this will be fetched from the output mentioned in the usermanagedidentity module
    role         = "Contributor"
  }
}

Deployment:



Refer:
azurerm_user_assigned_identity | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry

Thanks @Vinay for your help. I should have explained situation little better, the role_assignments in storage account module is not fixed, it could have one MSI or two or 10 MSI, thats why I did not added role_assignments in module itself.

In this example I showed two msi's, but there could be a need to add more than two MSIs and since the number of MSIs vary situation to situation basis I could not add role_assignment to child module.

If you have more number of MSI then you can use this
role_assignments = { for k in var.msi_names : "${k}_role_assignment" => {
principal_id = module.UserManagedIdentity[k].principal_id
role         = "Contributor"  # Default role, can be modified
}
}
this will be used by all MSI you mentioned in the tfvars so that you dont need to pass them on the root @Sandy

msi_names = [
"mi-test1",
"mi-test2",
"mi-test3",
"mi-test4",
"mi-test5",
"mi-test6,
.
.
soo on
]
we need to list them in this list format in tfvars

ok, how do we iterate this list in main.tf:(root)?

we no need to list the entire MSI inside root use the above mentioned role assignments in side module "storage_account" and list the n number of MSI in tfvars
